Uploading images using editor js
I'm trying to make an article editor using Editor.js, but I'm having trouble uploading images for the user. The tool itself is added, but when I try to upload an image an error pops up: “Couldn't upload image. Try another.”
The images are even thrown into a folder on beget, but an error pops up in the console:

Image Tool: uploading failed because of incorrect response: "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /public_html/News/SS.php:22\nStack trace:#0 {main}\n  thrown in /public_html/News/SS.php on line 22n" "

<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];


    $uploadDir = 'public_html/News/uploads/';
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($fileName);


    if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadFile)) {

        $imageUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $uploadFile;


        $response = [
            'url' => $imageUrl,
            'name' => $fileName,
            'size' => $fileSize,
            'type' => $fileType
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        echo 'Ошибка при загрузке файла.';
    }
    } else {
        echo 'Файл не был загружен.';
    }


JavaScript
const editor = new EditorJS({
    tools: {
      header: {
        class: Header,
        inlineToolbar: ['link']
      },
      embed: {
        class: Embed,
        inlineToolbar: false,
        config: {
          services: {
            youtube: true
          }
        }
      },
        list: {
        class: List,
        inlineToolbar: true,
        config: {
          defaultStyle: 'unordered'
        }
      },
      quote: {
        class: Quote,
        inlineToolbar: true,
        shortcut: 'CMD+SHIFT+O',
        config: {
          quotePlaceholder: 'Enter a quote',
          captionPlaceholder: 'Quote's author',
        },
      },
      imageSi: SimpleImage,
      image: {
        class: ImageTool,
        config: {
            endpoints: {
              byFile: 'http://n92576ob.beget.tech/News/SS.php', // Your backend file uploader endpoint
            }
            },
          },
        },
    holder: 'editorjs'
    });

So I tried to use a custom uploader thing instead of using endpoints, but that didn't bear much results.

The problem is with the PHP script's response and JSON encoding. The PHP script needs to be improved to generate the correct JSON response.
PHP Script
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];

    $uploadDir = 'News/uploads/';
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($fileName);

    if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadFile)) {
        $imageUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $uploadFile;

        $response = [
            'success' => 1,
            'file' => [
                'url' => $imageUrl,
                'name' => $fileName,
                'size' => $fileSize,
                'type' => $fileType
            ]
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response = [
            'success' => 0,
            'message' => 'Error uploading file.'
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response = [
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'No file uploaded.'
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

Explanation

The "Content-Type" header specified as "application/json" ensures
that the client recognizes the response as JSON.

The response is structured to align with the expectations of the
Editor. It includes a successful response and a file object with the
image details.

In case of failure, proper error messages are returned.


JS
Make sure your JavaScript configuration for Editor.js is pointing to the PHP script endpoint correctly. This is the relevant part:
const editor = new EditorJS({
    tools: {
        header: {
            class: Header,
            inlineToolbar: ['link']
        },
        embed: {
            class: Embed,
            inlineToolbar: false,
            config: {
                services: {
                    youtube: true
                }
            }
        },
        list: {
            class: List,
            inlineToolbar: true,
            config: {
                defaultStyle: 'unordered'
            }
        },
        quote: {
            class: Quote,
            inlineToolbar: true,
            shortcut: 'CMD+SHIFT+O',
            config: {
                quotePlaceholder: 'Enter a quote',
                captionPlaceholder: "Quote's author",
            },
        },
        image: {
            class: ImageTool,
            config: {
                endpoints: {
                    byFile: 'http://n92576ob.beget.tech/News/SS.php', // Your backend file uploader endpoint
                }
            }
        }
    },
    holder: 'editorjs'
});

Testing

Check directory News/uploads/ permissions.
Verify PHP file upload size limits.
Use browser tools to debug network requests and responses.

These adjustments will resolve your image upload issues and ensure that the Image Tool in Editor.js can handle the images without errors.
